# Elasticsearch : Is there a way to get an alert when a new agent joins the fleet?

Tags: elasticsearch, fleet

When a new agent joins the fleet, I want to make a few notes on my application. Is it possible to get a notification whenever a new agent joins to fleet?

I checked elasticsearch watcher but haven't found solution so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Tldr;

There are no built in mechanism to perform such a task.

Nonetheless it is possible to create it, but it will be a bit of a hack.

- Use the `.fleet-agents` index which won't be accessible in the 8.x releases
- Use the [Kibana agent api](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/tree/8.4/x-pack/plugins/fleet/common/openapi) which is in experimental state.

Comment: Thank you. We are using 8.x. I'll try out the api.